# Chrome Content Script (De)/Activate

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am trying to let users activate/deactivate a Chrome content script via a button.
It seems to me that the best way to do this is via chrome.browserAction.

But if I add

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "script.js"});
 });
```

to the background.html the script is running no matter if the button is pushed or not.
The rest of the script is running fine. The only issue is the browser button. 
Any ideas where the problem might be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `contentScript` is different from a `browserAction` or `pageAction`. If it is loaded in your `manifest.json` as a content script it will execute as though it were included in `<script>` tags on the page.

You can either use the Chrome [message passing API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) in the content script to check a variable in the background.html, or you can load the script as a [pageAction](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html), depending on which functionality suits you better.